# Handling the checkedchanged event of inner repeater Checkbox control in asp.net nested repeaters

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, nested, repeater

I have nested repeaters on my aspx page.In the outer repeater I am displaying a list of products and in the inner repeater I am displaying a list of additional options associated with each product.The inner repeater contains a checkbox,textbox,label and other stuff.I would like to find the controls inside the outer repeater when a user selects a checkbox in the inner repeater.In order to handle this I am using the following code.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="OuterRepeater" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="OuterRepeater_ItemDataBound" >
        <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="CodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Code") %>'></asp:Label>
     <asp:Repeater ID="InnerRepeater" runat="server" OnItemCreated="InnerRepeater_ItemCreated">
       <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"/> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
      ......
      .......
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
     ......
      ......
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>


 protected void InnerRepeater_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            RepeaterItem ri = (RepeaterItem)e.Item;

            if (ri.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || ri.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem
            )
            {
                CheckBox cb = ri.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
                cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBox1_CheckedChanged);
            }
        }

private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
              //do something
            }
        }
```

But the checkedChanged event of the checkbox is not firing for some reason.Also I am not sure how to access the textbox of the outer repeater in the checked changed event of the innter repeater checkbox control.

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not fire the CheckedChanged event, since you have declared the event handler as `private`, You have to make it `Protected or Public`

```
Protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

You can access the Textbox control like..

```
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
  Textbox textbox1 = (TextBox)checkBox.Parent.FindControl("TextBox1");
  String textboxText = textbox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Sorry,where am I supposed to specify the checked eventhandler? I am binding the checkedchanged eventhandler to the checkbox in the inner repeater itemcreated event.

Comment: Ok,I had some js error before I think and so the event was not firing.But now its firing even with the 'private' modifier.I just wonder is it mandatory to change it to 'protected' as it is accessed just inside the same file?

Comment: Also I tried to find the textbox in the outer repeater using the code sample provided.But it doesn't work.It returns null.

Comment: Ok,I am able to access the outer repeater controls by modifying the code you provided.But still I am not sure if its mandatory to change the modifier to 'protected' from 'private'.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you defined an event handler in your markup.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
```

Comment: As @Muhammad suggested, you also need to use public or protected too.

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad Akhtar's answer helped me a lot today!
I just needed to set a specific ID to my dynamic generated checkboxes inside my reapeater to recover the origin of the event, and do the rest of the processing, and it worked perfectly.

```
chkAtivo.ID = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "id").ToString();
```

Reovered just as the sample.
Cant vote up yet, but thank you.